# Separating an Array with commas

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I want to convert this array with a length of 1:

```
var myArray = ("The,boy,and,the,girl")
```

to an array with a length of 5:

```
myArray = ("The","boy","and","the","girl")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `.split()` on the string in your array:

```
myArray  = myArray[0].split(",");
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001555.html

Comment: Thanks. Oddly enough, I was so focused on the more difficult task (for me) of loading a text file, then adding the commas where the spaces were that I wasn't thinking clearly.